# Is the finite element method easily extrapolable to new disciplines?

Tags: education, computational-physics

I am a structural engineer with a good solid mechanics background. I am reasonably familiar with finite element methods as applied to linear/nonlinear solids and structures,

I would like to know how extrapolable the finite element method is to disciplines beyond my own. Given a solid mathematical and physical understanding of solid mechanics problems in FEM, could I easily extrapolate this to other sciences like Fluid Mechanics, Heat Transfer, Electricity and Magnetism, etc...?

In other words, could finite elements be taught in such a way as to be blind to the discipline and applicable to brand new fields?

Comment: In short: yes, very useful. But the question is way too broad to be answered in full generality here in a couple paragraphs.

Comment: Well it seems to me that in order to *apply* FEM to those other cases, you actually have to *learn the subjects* you are modeling. Note, though, that FEM *is* being used in fluid mechanics, heat transfer, E&M, etc (see [Comsol](https://www.comsol.com/books/mmwfem), for instance; can't tell if you're not aware of this from your post).

Comment: Absolutely! Finite element analysis is indeed used in many disciplines - structural mechanics, thermal diffusion, optical diffusion, electron optics, and magnet design are just five areas in which I have used it personally. There must be many others. The problem is that if the course is taught as part of "structural engineering", it tends to cover just one aspect. When it's "applied mathematics" or "computational methods", it is more likely that it could be blind to the discipline. But inevitably, in teaching you will want to apply the methods to a "real" problem...